# Float or double type in terms of storage and memory

Tags: java, memory, double, heap-memory

I am parsing data where precision is not my main concern. I often get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError even if I use maximum Java heap size. So my main concern here is memory usage, and java heap space. Should I use double or float data type?

Comment: You have to increase the heap size, but what are you doing that you get consistently OOM exceptions?

Comment: As with the recommendations for byte and short, use a float (instead of double) if you need to save memory in large arrays of floating point numbers [Oracle Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: float takes up 4 bytes and double takes 8 bytes of storage. So, based on your usage/data size the answer should be obvious. But what exactly are you trying to do and how are you setting the heap size? Could you please provide more information? It might be something else entirely.

Comment: If precision isn't your main concern you should use a float, or long, or int, or short, or byte, or bit. At some point it *will* become your main concern. Only you know where that point is.

Comment: I consistently get OOM exceptions because I use a great number of ArrayLists with numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your memory usage is related to a huge amount (many millions) of floating-point numbers (which can be verified with a decent memory profiler), then you're most probably storing them in some data structures like arrays or lists.

Recommendations (I guess, you are already following most of them...):

- Prefer `float` over `double` if number range and precision are sufficient, as that consumes only half the size.
- Do not use the `java.lang.Float` or `java.lang.Double` classes for storage, as they hav a considerable memory overhead compared to the naked scalar values.
- Be sure to use arrays, not collections like `java.util.List`, as they store boxed `java.lang.Float` instances instead of the naked numbers.

But above that, have a decent memory profiler show you which instances occupy most of your memory. Maybe there are other memory consumers besides the float/double data.

EDIT:

The OP's recent comment "I consistently get OOM exceptions because I use a great number of ArrayLists with numbers" makes it clear. `ArrayList<Float>` wastes a lot of memory when compared to `float[]` (Stephen C gave detailed numbers in his answer), but gives the benefit of dynamic resizing.

So, I see the following possibilities:

- If you can tell the array size from the beginning, then immediately use `float[]` arrays.
- If you need the dynamic size while initializing instances, use `ArrayList<Float>` while building one object (when size still increases), and then copy the contents to a `float[]` array for long-term storage. Then the wasteful ArrayLists exist only for a limited timespan.
- If you need dynamic sizes over the whole lifespan of your data, create your own `FloatArrayList` class based on a `float[]` array, resembling the `ArrayList<Float>` as far as your code needs it (that can range from a very shallow implementation up to a full-featured List, maybe based on `AbstractList`).

Answer (score 4):

> I consistently get OOM exceptions because I use a great number of ArrayLists with numbers.

Well **that** is your problem!

- An `ArrayList` of N 32-bit floating point values takes at least<sup>1</sup> 20 * N bytes in a 32-bit JVM and 24 * N bytes in a 64-bit JVM<sup>2</sup>.
- An `ArrayList` of N 64-bit floating point values takes **the same amount of space**<sup>3</sup>.
- The above only accounts for the backing array and the list elements.  If you have huge numbers of small `ArrayList` objects, the overhead of the `ArrayList` object itself may be significant.  (Add 16 or 24 bytes for each `ArrayList` object`.)
- If you make use of dynamic resizing, this may generate object churn as the backing array grows.  At some points, the backing array may be as much as twice as large as it needs to be.

By contrast:

- An array of 32-bit floating point values takes approximately 4 * N bytes<sup>4</sup>.
- An array of 64-bit floating point values takes approximately 8 * N bytes<sup>4</sup>.
- There is no wastage due to dynamic resizing.  But you need to specify the correct size at allocation time.

Solutions:

1. `ArrayList<Float>` versus `ArrayList<Double>` makes no difference.  It is NOT a solution
2. For maximal saving, use `float[]` or `double[]` depending on your precision requirements.  Preallocate the arrays to hold the exact number of elements required.
3. If you want the flexibility of dynamic resizing there are 3rd-party libraries that implement space efficient lists of primitive types.  Alternatively implement your own.  However, you won't be able to use the standard `List<...>` API because that forces you down the path of using `Float` OR `Double`.

---

<sup>1 - The actual space used depends on how the `ArrayList` was created and populated.  If you pre-allocate an `ArrayList` with exactly the correct capacity, you will use the space I said above.  If you build the array by repeatedly appending to an `ArrayList` with the default initial capacity, you will use *on average* N * 2 bytes extra space for a 32-bit JVM.  This is due to the heuristic that `ArrayList` uses to grow the backing array when it is full.

2 - On a 64-bit JVM, a pointer occupies 8 bytes rather than 4 ... unless you are using compressed oops.

3 - The reason it takes the same amount of bytes is that on a typical JVM a `Float` and a `Double` are both 16 bytes due to heap node padding.

4 - There is a header overhead of (typically) 12 bytes per array, and the array's heap node size is padded to a multiple of 8 bytes.</sup>